# Kafka Connect, Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-connect

Installed a connector for MongoDB using docker. but in the connector list (curl -s -XGET http: // localhost: 8083 / connector-plugins | jq '. []. class')
it is not displayed. what could be the problem? my docker file

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:5.5.0
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.4.0
```

Thanks for feedback

Comment: Did you override the plugin path at runtime?

Comment: no. how it works? do you have an example?

Comment: Can you show your docker run command?

Comment: I use docker-compose by confluent

Comment: with 
`
CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
`

Comment: Why do your `curl` the address `localhost`? Where are you `curl`ing? What's the container port? Is that `8083`? Or it's `80`?

Comment: container port is 8083

Comment: _I use docker-compose by confluent_ - Did you change the image that is used in the Compose to your own image that includes the Mongo connector?

Comment: added folder with unpacked jar - archive to variable
CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/home/madmin/connectors"
In /home/madmin/connector - unpacked mongo connector

Comment: /home/madmin doesn't exist in your docker image. You've already installed the connector in the image using confluent-hub, so why are you downloading and extracting things in your host machine? And you didn't answer my question - you've written your own dockerfile, but do you ever build it, or actually use it via Compose?